# MySql how to get a name based on a primary in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to show some data from the database. The id of the boss is in the same row as an employee. I want to display the name of the boss. eId is the id of the employee and bossId is the id of his boss. recepId is the id of the receptionist of that department.

I want to show the department name, description, id of the receptionist, name of the receptionist, id of the boss and his name.

I can display everything except the name of the boss. How do manage that inside my query?

Employee table:

```
| eId          | name        |city           |bossId  | depNr |
|:-------------|------------:|:------------:|--------------------
| 345          |  Frits      |    Canvas    |  240    |  60|
| 240          |  Steven     |    Canvas    |  200    |  90|
| 265          |  John       |    Kentucky  |  40     |  60|
| 40           |  Kreuger    |    Kentucky  |         |  90|
```

Department table:

```
| depCode      | depName       |locId       |recepId|
|:-------------|------------:  |:-----------|----------
| 60           |  Finance      |  CAN       | 345    |
| 90           |  Research     |  CAN       | 265    |
```

Location table:

```
| code         | description   |country     |
|:-------------|------------:  |:-----------|
| CAN          |  Finance      |  USA       | 
| CAN          |  Research     |  USA       |
| KEN          |  Economics    |  USA       |
```

What I want:

```
| depName      | description |recepId       |name     | bossID| bossName|
|:-------------|------------:|:------------:|----------------------------
| 345          |  COD12      |    Canvas    |  Frits  |  240  | Steven
| 140          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  John   |  800  | Kreuger
```

My query:

```
SELECT department.depName, Location.description, department.recepId, employee.name, employee.bossId
FROM department 
INNER JOIN Location
ON Location.code = department.locId
Left JOIN employee
ON department.recepId = employee.eId
```

This shows:

```
| depName      | description |recepId       |name     | bossID|
|:-------------|------------:|:------------:|-------------------
| 345          |  COD12      |    Canvas    |  Frits  |  240  | 
| 140          |  COD40      |    Canvas    |  John   |  800  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join with `employee` again to get the boss's name.

```
SELECT department.depName, Location.description, department.recepId, 
        employee.name, employee.bossId, boss.name AS bossName
FROM department 
INNER JOIN Location
ON Location.code = department.locId
Left JOIN employee
ON department.recepId = employee.eId
LEFT JOIN employee AS boss
ON employee.bossId = boss.eId
```